# Unit test with primeng

Tags: angular, unit-testing, primeng

I try to write my first unit test on a component in which I used some primeng components.

When I run "ng test" I got this error :

```
Chrome 63.0.3239 (Linux 0.0.0) HeaderComponent should create FAILED
    1. If 'p-dropdown' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'p-dropdown' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
    3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("header-text">
            <p-dropdown [options]="languages" (onChange)="onDropdownChange($event.value)" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage"></p-dropdown>
        </div>
```

Not sure about what I need to do? Do I need to inject or mock anything?

Here my unit test (basically the generated one) :

```
describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [HeaderComponent]

    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Thx

Comment: Have you imported "DropdownModule" into your app.module.ts?

Comment: No but it's imported in the module that contains this component

Comment: You have to import that in the testing module too. Show your spec file.

Comment: I've added my spec

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you add the `NO_ERROR_SCHEMA` to ignore child components.
In case  you want to use the slider in a test it is better to mock it. Lib called **ngMocks** is the most common way to mock it out and it has the ability to assert on it's inputs or emit on an output to assert on a side effect.

[ngMocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks) can be adde via npm: `npm i ng-mocks`

For example mocking out `p-slider` component would look like this:

```js
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {MockComponent} from 'ng-mocks'; //step 1: add mock util function
import {Slider, SliderModule} from 'primeng/slider'; // setp 2: Mocked component and it's module

import {DateRangePickerComponent} from './date-range-picker.component';

describe('DateRangePickerComponent', () => {
    let component: DateRangePickerComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DateRangePickerComponent>;

    beforeEach(
        async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [SliderModule], // add mocked comp's module
                declarations: [
                DateRangePickerComponent, 
                MockComponent(Slider) //actual mocking 
                ]  
            }).compileComponents();
        })
    );

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DateRangePickerComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Comment: ngMocks is great for clearing out errors and building a component, but how can you use it to actually test that the event handlers from primeng actually hit your methods?

Answer (score 2):

Add NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA in schemas, This is a way to ignore child components while unit testing.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [DropdownModule],
    declarations: [ HeaderComponent ],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]   // <-- Add This Line. (make sure to import NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA)
  })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```

Comment: don't do this:
https://medium.com/@fivedicephoto/why-you-shouldnt-use-no-errors-schema-in-angular-unit-tests-cdd478c30782

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the module in your testbed:

```
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [DropdownModule],
      declarations: [HeaderComponent]

    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```